# How can i eliminate duplicate string in the displayed parameter

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I created a multi select parameter in crystal report and I created a formula using the JOIN function to combine all the selected string in the parameter and I place it in the header section of the report. But the problem the other strings are duplicated, can someone help me to remove the duplicated sting in the line.

here's my sample formula:
`JOIN({?SELECT branch FROM myTable ORDER BY 1 ASC},", ")`

here's my output result:
[image]

As you can see guys the BAGU and DAGU are displayed 2 times.

Regards,

Alex

Comment: select Distinct branch

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: trim the string

Comment: Just the same output. I used TRIM(string) / RTRIM and LTRIM

Comment: analyse the data in the table because distinct should eliminate the duplicate